# Can i get Source Path of Installed application?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

is there any way to know that form which path an application was installed.

for example I have firefox.exe in

```
D:\Downloads\App\firefox.exe
```

and when I install it, it is installed in

```
C:\Program Files\Firefox
```

but for some reason I need path from where Firefox was installed. that is "D:\Downloads\App\".

like if this path is stored in some registry value? or in some other system variables? is there any way to get that path? I would like to get that path and then store it in some text file

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to use this path to download different applications on that path using Kaseya procedure. but As i dont know path of source folder so this is what i can think about.

Answer (score 3):

**Some** installs will create a registry key 'InstallSource' with the uninstall information here:

> HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*\
>   HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*\

For example:

```
...\Uninstall\{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}\InstallSource = c:\22e11d77ed4216e686b789\
...\Uninstall\{343D4507-997F-4553-9F86-2BB81F19A05E}\InstallSource = C:\WINDOWS\ccmsetup\{72875A95-4007-4DAC-88D8-66366F9A5045}\
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application includes an installation log then it may contain the source path for the install files but the chances are slim (I've checked the install log for Firefox and it has no mention of the source file) as such I'm inclined to say it's not possible to identify the source install for your programs but you shouldn't need to know where the install files where only where the program was installed.

I'm not familiar with Kaseya but the [forum post](http://community.kaseya.com/xsp/f/28/t/15241.aspx) might help

Answer (score 0):

In Kaseya you need to specify the working directory. By default this is C:\kworking. For agent procedures you need to know where you saved a file on the machine if you are going to do anything with it. If you saved a file with Kaseya previously and don't know where it went the first thing you should do is go to LiveConnect and look at where the working directory for the machine is. You can also review the agent logs.